# Electron: mocking out network requests for tests

Tags: unit-testing, testing, electron, nock, electron.net

I'd like to write unit tests for some of my network logic in an Electron app, and need to mock out the network endpoints.

In the past, I've used `nock` for mocking out HTTP requests in Node.  However, my Electron code uses the `electron.net` module for requests (instead of Node's `http` module), and Nock doesn't intercept these requests.

What is the best way to mock Electron network requests?

Answer (score 0):

You can easily mock your API with Postman:
https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/mock-servers/setting-up-mock/

Comment: Unless you pay for premium Postman services, there are rate limits, including a **max of 1000 requests per month**. Eventually you will receive a `429` stating: `Your team plan allows 1000 mock server calls per month. Contact your team Admin to up your limit.`

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend this simple, platform independent, and open source tool for *local* testing:

https://www.electronjs.org/apps/local-mock-server

This is *much simpler* than paid-for options like postman, but I'm guessing the author would be very amenable to enhancements if you propose a PR here:

https://github.com/jayakumarreddy/Local-Mock-Server/

The configuration simply lives in your home directory (`~/.config/local-mock-server/mocks_folder/` on Linux), so what I do is simply check these mocks into my git repo and symlink them there, that way everything I do is repeatable for someone else. Just double click the AppImage (on Linux) to enable the mock and leave it minimized for as long as needed. Done.